# What UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file stores?

Tags: ios, xcode

Started a new project in Xcode, and although I change only some codeine, `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` file become always part of the stage files. Why, what is this file good for?

Answer (score 0):

It just manages the state of XCode. You don't need to store this for any reason and `*.xcuserstate` should probably be added to your `.gitignore` file.